# How to change the Default color of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, colors, awt, background-color

I am adding the background color to the My JFrame program.But,In my program I was add Menubar and Tollbar to JFrame.Here The background color is applied upto Toolbar.I want to avoid the background color for Tollbar.I want to apply background color after the Toolbar.Please help me.Thank you in Advance.

My code is:

```
public class JFrameDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public JFrameDemo() {

   Color b=new Color(0,150,255);
   getContentPane().setBackground(b);
   initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tollBar = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    tollBar.setRollover(true);

    jMenu1.setText("File");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("Edit");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tollBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(tollBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 254, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Icons\book-edit-icon.png");
            JFrameDemo fdemo=new JFrameDemo();

            fdemo.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JToolBar tollBar;
// End of variables declaration                   }
```

Comment: add a JPanel to your JFrame and change it's color. the menubar will not be affected

Comment: `if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {` Why not just use a different PLAF (that draws the BG color of toolbars a nicer color)?

Comment: Thank you.Please provide sample example code.

Comment: please set backcolor to toolbar

Answer (score 0):

```
container=getContentPane();
container.setBackground(Color.white);
```